# Statically allocate string array with an initial size

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm working on a system in which I cannot use dynamic allocation.

I want to have an array of strings which will be filled later.

To my understanding, using

```
string myArr[20];
```

will not work, as when I will call

```
myArr[5] = newString
```

the copy constructor will allocate new memory dynamically, because the initial length is zero.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use some static string implementation, such as [`static_string` from Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/static_string/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: It's not possible to statically allocate **a std::string**. Full stop. You must use char arrays for this purpose.

Comment: @user253751 IIRC, `std::string` internally allocates with `operator new` (via `std::allocator<char>`), which may be user-replaced. In theory, one can thus have some statically allocated memory pool and use it for `std::string` without heap dynamic memory allocations. I wouldn't recommend it at all, just saying it should be possible.

Comment: @DanielLangr It would still be dynamic allocation

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I agree, but I guess it would be ok with OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the dynamic memory allocations comes from the fact that you are using [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), not from the C-like array. If you want to avoid that use const char* instead of [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Secondly, I believe it's generally discouraged to use C-like arrays in C++. If you are working with C++11 or later version you can use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it requires coding or external library, just to give you a basic idea :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

// helper class to just give a basic idea, there are better libaries out there :)
// statically allocates a string buffer of (N+1) chars
template<size_t N>
class static_string
{
public:
    static_string() = default;
    ~static_string() = default;

    void operator=(const std::string& str)
    {
        str.copy(&m_str[0], std::min(str.length(),N) + 1); // string plus trailing 0
    }

    const char* c_str() const noexcept
    {
        return &m_str[0];
    }

private:
    std::array<char, N + 1> m_str{}; // init to zero, zo last char is also always *
};



int main()
{
    std::array<static_string<4>, 5> strings;
    strings[3] = "Hello world!"; // only will assign first 4 characters, will not resize memory

    // outputs a truncated string
    std::cout << strings[3].c_str();

    return 0;
}
```